# xp_cmdshell - The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to execute `xp_cmdshell` without success. The exe file to execute is at `c:\program files (x86)\internet download manager\`

and I get the following error message:

> The system cannot find the path specified

The command line is:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'MPR01\\program files (x86)\internet download manager\idman  /n
```

MPR01 is the name of the server. I have also tried without the name of the server - and makes no difference.

Answer (score 3):

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell '"\\MPR01\C$\program files (x86)\internet download manager\idman" /n';
```

The server name has a double backslash at the beginning.
C$ is a system share.
And I added double quotes because the path has spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, In order to use this you need to configure the SQL Server to gain the access to execute the Shell commands,

```
---- To allow advanced options to be changed.
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
-- To enable the feature.  
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;  
GO  
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

Then execute your actual command. (Make sure to have proper open and close  single quotes)

```
xp_cmdshell '%windir%\system32\<Your .EXE>';
```

In case of special permissions are needed; use the below context,

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = '<other_login>' ;  
GO  
xp_cmdshell '%windir%\system32\<Your .EXE>';
REVERT ;
```

Comment: Thank you. I followed your steps and still get the same error message.
I tried: 
xp_cmdshell 'windir%\program files (x86)\internet download manager\idman.exe /n'


xp_cmdshell 'windir%\system32\program files (x86)\internet download manager\idman.exe /n';

Comment: Try executing the same from a command prompt. If there are no syntax errors, tune it further to get it executed in SSMS

Comment: Hi, from a command promt works so long as I am in the directory called:
c:\program files (x86)\internet download manager\  

Otherwise I get the same error message again

Comment: You have to enable permissions for "Everyone" on Import folder. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62056607/2119941

Answer (score 1):

xp_cmdshell is disabled by default, because it poses security risk.

### You need to execute in this order to enable xp_cmdshell

1. Allow advanced options to be changed:

> ```
> EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
> GO
> ```

2. Enable xp_cmdshell:

> `EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1; GO`

3. Update the currently configured value for advanced options:

> ```
> RECONFIGURE;
> GO
> ```

After that enable permissions for `"Everyone"` on Import folder which you are trying to access with xp_cmdshell. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/62056607/2119941).