# Import multiple delimited text files into a SQL Server database and automatically create tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, import, create-table

I have multiple delimited text files (e.g. `.csv` files), each containing columns, rows and a header.

I want to import all of these input files into SQL Server with as much ease as possible. Specifically, I want to create the output tables into which I will import these files *on the fly*.

Some of these input files will need to be imported into one and the same output table, while others will need to be imported to different tables. You can assume that all files which will be imported into the same table have the same header.

SQL Server Management Studio has an *Import Wizard* which allows you to import delimited text files (and other formats) and automatically create the output table. However, this does not allow you to import multiple files at the same time. Furthermore, it requires a lot of manual work and is not replicable.

One can find many scripts online which import multiple text files into a table. However, most of these require the output table to be created first. This too, requires additional work per table.

Is there a way to list all relevant input files and their corresponding output table, such that the tables are created automatically followed by the importing of the data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This script allows you to import multiple *delimited text files* into a **SQL database**. The tables into which the data is imported, including all required columns, are created *automatically*. The script includes some documentation.

```
/*
**  This file was created by Laurens Bogaardt, Advisor Data Analytics at EY Amsterdam on 2016-11-03.
**  This script allows you to import multiple delimited text files into a SQL database. The tables 
**  into which the data is imported, including all required columns, are created automatically. This 
**  script uses tab-delimited (tsv) files and SQL Server Management Studio. The script may need some 
**  minor adjustments for other formats and tools. The scripts makes several assumptions which need 
**  to be valid before it can run properly. First of all, it assumes none of the output tables exist 
**  in the SQL tool before starting. Therefore, it may be necessary to clean the database and delete 
**  all the existing tables. Secondly, the script assumes that, if multiple text files are imported 
**  into the same output table, the number and order of the columns of these files is identical. If 
**  this is not the case, some manual work may need to be done to the text files before importing.
**  Finally, please note that this script only imports data as strings (to be precise, as NVARCHAR's
**  of length 255). It does not allow you to specify the datatype per column. This would need to be 
**  done using another script after importing the data as strings.
*/

-- 1.   Import Multiple Delimited Text Files into a SQL Database

-- 1.1  Define the path to the input and define the terminators

/*
**  In this section, some initial parameters are set. Obviously, the 'DatabaseName' refers to the 
**  database in which you want to create new tables. The '@Path' parameter sets the folder in 
**  which the text files are located which you want to import. Delimited files are defined by 
**  two characters: one which separates columns and one which separates rows. Usually, the 
**  row-terminator is the newline character CHAR(10), also given by '\n'. When files are created 
**  in Windows, the row-terminator often includes a carriage return CHAR(13), also given by '\r\n'. 
**  Often, a tab is used to separate each column. This is given by CHAR(9) or by the character '\t'. 
**  Other useful characters include the comma CHAR(44), the semi-colon CHAR(59) and the pipe 
**  CHAR(124).
*/

USE [DatabaseName]
DECLARE @Path NVARCHAR(255) = 'C:\\PathToFiles\\'
DECLARE @RowTerminator NVARCHAR(5) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
DECLARE @ColumnTerminator NVARCHAR(5) = CHAR(9)

-- 1.2  Define the list of input and output in a temporary table

/*
**  In this section, a temporary table is created which lists all the filenames of the delimited 
**  files which need to be imported, as well as the names of the tables which are created and into 
**  which the data is imported. Multiple files may be imported into the same output table. Each row 
**  is prepended with an integer which increments up starting from 1. It is essential that this 
**  number follows this logic. The temporary table is deleted at the end of this script.
*/

IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Files_Temporary]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Files_Temporary];
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Files_Temporary]
(
    [ID] INT
    , [FileName] NVARCHAR(255)
    , [TableName] NVARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Files_Temporary] SELECT 1,   'MyFileA.txt',  'NewTable1'
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Files_Temporary] SELECT 2,   'MyFileB.txt',  'NewTable2'
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Files_Temporary] SELECT 3,   'MyFileC.tsv',  'NewTable2'
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Files_Temporary] SELECT 4,   'MyFileD.csv',  'NewTable2'
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Files_Temporary] SELECT 5,   'MyFileE.dat',  'NewTable2'
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Files_Temporary] SELECT 6,   'MyFileF',      'NewTable3'
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Files_Temporary] SELECT 7,   'MyFileG.text', 'NewTable4'
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Files_Temporary] SELECT 8,   'MyFileH.txt',  'NewTable5'
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Files_Temporary] SELECT 9,   'MyFileI.txt',  'NewTable5'
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Files_Temporary] SELECT 10,  'MyFileJ.txt',  'NewTable5'
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Files_Temporary] SELECT 11,  'MyFileK.txt',  'NewTable6'

-- 1.3  Loop over the list of input and output and import each file to the correct table

/*
**  In this section, the 'WHILE' statement is used to loop over all input files. A counter is defined 
**  which starts at '1' and increments with each iteration. The filename and tablename are retrieved 
**  from the previously defined temporary table. The next step of the script is to check whether the 
**  output table already exists or not.
*/

DECLARE @Counter INT = 1

WHILE @Counter <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Files_Temporary])
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Counter is ''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), @Counter) + '''.'

    DECLARE @FileName NVARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @Header NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @SQL_Header NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @CreateHeader NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    DECLARE @SQL_CreateHeader NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @FileName = [FileName], @TableName = [TableName] FROM [dbo].[Files_Temporary] WHERE [ID] = @Counter

    IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[' + @TableName + ']', 'U') IS NULL
    BEGIN
/*
**  If the output table does not yet exist, it needs to be created. This requires the list of all 
**  columnnames for that table to be retrieved from the first line of the text file, which includes 
**  the header. A piece of SQL code is generated and executed which imports the header of the text 
**  file. A second temporary table is created which stores this header as a single string.
*/
        PRINT 'Creating new table with name ''' + @TableName + '''.'

        IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Header_Temporary]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE [dbo].[Header_Temporary];
        CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Header_Temporary]
        (
            [Header] NVARCHAR(MAX)
        );

        SET @SQL_Header = '
            BULK INSERT [dbo].[Header_Temporary]
            FROM ''' + @Path + @FileName + '''
            WITH
            (
                FIRSTROW = 1,
                LASTROW = 1,
                MAXERRORS = 0,
                FIELDTERMINATOR = ''' + @RowTerminator + ''',
                ROWTERMINATOR = ''' + @RowTerminator + '''
            )'
        EXEC(@SQL_Header)

        SET @Header = (SELECT TOP 1 [Header] FROM [dbo].[Header_Temporary])
        PRINT 'Extracted header ''' + @Header + ''' for table ''' + @TableName + '''.'
/*
**  The columnnames in the header are separated using the column-terminator. This can be used to loop 
**  over each columnname. A new piece of SQL code is generated which will create the output table 
**  with the correctly named columns.
*/
        WHILE CHARINDEX(@ColumnTerminator, @Header) > 0
        BEGIN          
            SET @CreateHeader = @CreateHeader + '[' + LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@Header, 1, CHARINDEX(@ColumnTerminator, @Header) - 1))) + '] NVARCHAR(255), '
            SET @Header = SUBSTRING(@Header, CHARINDEX(@ColumnTerminator, @Header) + 1, LEN(@Header)) 
        END
        SET @CreateHeader = @CreateHeader + '[' + @Header + '] NVARCHAR(255)'

        SET @SQL_CreateHeader = 'CREATE TABLE [' + @TableName + '] (' + @CreateHeader + ')'
        EXEC(@SQL_CreateHeader)
    END

/*
**  Finally, the data from the text file is imported into the newly created table. The first line, 
**  including the header information, is skipped. If multiple text files are imported into the same 
**  output table, it is essential that the number and the order of the columns is identical, as the 
**  table will only be created once, using the header information of the first text file.
*/
    PRINT 'Inserting data from ''' + @FileName + ''' to ''' + @TableName + '''.'
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SQL = '
        BULK INSERT [dbo].[' + @TableName + ']
        FROM ''' + @Path + @FileName + '''
        WITH
        (
            FIRSTROW = 2,
            MAXERRORS = 0,
            FIELDTERMINATOR = ''' + @ColumnTerminator + ''',
            ROWTERMINATOR = ''' + @RowTerminator + '''
        )'
    EXEC(@SQL)

    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
END;

-- 1.4  Cleanup temporary tables

/*
**  In this section, the temporary tables which were created and used by this script are deleted. 
**  Alternatively, the script could have used 'real' temporary table (identified by the '#' character 
**  in front of the name) or a table variable. These would have deleted themselves once they were no 
**  longer in use. However, the end result is the same.
*/

IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Files_Temporary]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Files_Temporary];

IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Header_Temporary]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Header_Temporary];
```

Comment: This is such a well written answer. A small tweak I would suggest is rather than inserting the file and table names manually the below statement could be used to populate the table automatically,


------Insert file names ------

insert into Files_Temporary (filename)  exec master..xp_cmdshell 'dir <<Folder path where the files reside>> /b /a-d'
------Update table names eliminating the file extension-------
update Files_Temporary set [TableName]= SUBSTRING(filename,0, CHARINDEX('.',filename))

Answer (score 3):

## Inserting whole folder with delimited .txt or .csv files into SQL server

*Note: Don't be scared of lenghty script you'll see here. There is only 3 variables that needs changing and whole script should work fine.*

This solution is upgrade from accepted answer (@LBogaardt) and it also implement suggestion from @Chendur Mar for getting all files from folder.

**My additions:**

- this solution works with UTF-8 files
- imports in `NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead in `NVARCHAR(255)` - you can change that if you wish
- has [error logging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13129140/2119941) implemented so you can see on which row import breaks in case that happens

### STEP 1 - ENABLE xp_cmdshell

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62056743/2119941) on how to do that.

### STEP 2 - ENABLE permissions for everyone on Import folder

Keep on your mind - Import folder is remote folder on server. So you need to create folder on server and upload your files there.
Set permissions on that folder following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62056607/2119941).

### STEP 3 - Edit script parameters and execute it

**You only have to change first 4 lines:**

1. Line - instead of `yourDatabase`, put name of your database
2. Line - define location of your Import folder where your .txt .csv files are
3. Line - define row terminator which is most likely `new line`(`\n`) so keep it as is
4. Line - define separator for your files - if you use comma than put `CHAR(44)` or `','`. CHAR(9) is TAB.

Script:

```
USE yourDatabase
DECLARE @Location NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\Import\';
DECLARE @RowTerminator NVARCHAR(5) = '\n';
DECLARE @ColumnTerminator NVARCHAR(5) = CHAR(9);

DECLARE @SQLINSERT NVARCHAR(MAX);


-- 1.2  Define the list of input and output in a temporary table

/*
**  In this section, a temporary table is created which lists all the filenames of the delimited
**  files which need to be imported, as well as the names of the tables which are created and into
**  which the data is imported. Multiple files may be imported into the same output table. Each row
**  is prepended with an integer which increments up starting from 1. It is essential that this
**  number follows this logic. The temporary table is deleted at the end of this script.
*/

IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Files_Temporary]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Files_Temporary];
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Files_Temporary]
(
    [ID] INT identity (1,1) primary key
    , [FileName] NVARCHAR(max)
    , [TableName] NVARCHAR(max)
);

--insert names into  [dbo].[Files_Temporary] 
SET @SQLINSERT = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[Files_Temporary] (filename) exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell' + char(39) + ' dir ' + @Location + ' /b /a-d' + char(39)
EXEC(@SQLINSERT)
------Update table names eliminating the file extension-------
update [dbo].[Files_Temporary] set [TableName]= SUBSTRING(filename,0, CHARINDEX('.',filename))

-- 1.3  Loop over the list of input and output and import each file to the correct table

/*
**  In this section, the 'WHILE' statement is used to loop over all input files. A counter is defined
**  which starts at '1' and increments with each iteration. The filename and tablename are retrieved
**  from the previously defined temporary table. The next step of the script is to check whether the
**  output table already exists or not.
*/

DECLARE @Counter INT = 1

WHILE @Counter <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Files_Temporary])
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Counter is ''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), @Counter) + '''.'

    DECLARE @FileName NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @Header NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @SQL_Header NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @CreateHeader NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    DECLARE @SQL_CreateHeader NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @FileName = [FileName], @TableName = [TableName] FROM [dbo].[Files_Temporary] WHERE [ID] = @Counter

    IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[' + @TableName + ']', 'U') IS NULL
    BEGIN
/*
**  If the output table does not yet exist, it needs to be created. This requires the list of all
**  columnnames for that table to be retrieved from the first line of the text file, which includes
**  the header. A piece of SQL code is generated and executed which imports the header of the text
**  file. A second temporary table is created which stores this header as a single string.
*/
        PRINT 'Creating new table with name ''' + @TableName + '''.'

        IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Header_Temporary]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE [dbo].[Header_Temporary];
        CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Header_Temporary]
        (
            [Header] NVARCHAR(MAX)
        );

        SET @SQL_Header = '
            BULK INSERT [dbo].[Header_Temporary]
            FROM ''' + @Location + @FileName + '''
            WITH
            (
                FIRSTROW = 1,
                LASTROW = 1,
                MAXERRORS = 0,
                FIELDTERMINATOR = ''' + @RowTerminator + ''',
                ROWTERMINATOR = ''' + @RowTerminator + '''
            )'
        EXEC(@SQL_Header)

        SET @Header = (SELECT TOP 1 [Header] FROM [dbo].[Header_Temporary])
        PRINT 'Extracted header ''' + @Header + ''' for table ''' + @TableName + '''.'
/*
**  The columnnames in the header are separated using the column-terminator. This can be used to loop
**  over each columnname. A new piece of SQL code is generated which will create the output table
**  with the correctly named columns.
*/
        WHILE CHARINDEX(@ColumnTerminator, @Header) > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @CreateHeader = @CreateHeader + '[' + LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@Header, 1, CHARINDEX(@ColumnTerminator, @Header) - 1))) + '] NVARCHAR(MAX), '
            SET @Header = SUBSTRING(@Header, CHARINDEX(@ColumnTerminator, @Header) + 1, LEN(@Header))
        END
        SET @CreateHeader = @CreateHeader + '[' + @Header + '] NVARCHAR(MAX)'

        SET @SQL_CreateHeader = 'CREATE TABLE [ESCO].[' + @TableName + '] (' + @CreateHeader + ')'
        EXEC(@SQL_CreateHeader)
    END

/*
**  Finally, the data from the text file is imported into the newly created table. The first line,
**  including the header information, is skipped. If multiple text files are imported into the same
**  output table, it is essential that the number and the order of the columns is identical, as the
**  table will only be created once, using the header information of the first text file.
*/
    --bulk insert

    PRINT 'Inserting data from ''' + @FileName + ''' to ''' + @TableName + '''.'
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SQL = '
        BULK INSERT [dbo].[' + @TableName + ']
        FROM ''' + @Location + @FileName + '''
        WITH
        (
            FIRSTROW = 2,
            MAXERRORS = 0,
            FIELDTERMINATOR = ''' + @ColumnTerminator + ''',
            ROWTERMINATOR = ''' + @RowTerminator + ''',
            CODEPAGE = ''65001'',
            DATAFILETYPE = ''Char'',
            ERRORFILE = ''' + @Location + 'ImportLog.log''
        )'
    EXEC(@SQL)

    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
END;

-- 1.4  Cleanup temporary tables

/*
**  In this section, the temporary tables which were created and used by this script are deleted.
**  Alternatively, the script could have used 'real' temporary table (identified by the '#' character
**  in front of the name) or a table variable. These would have deleted themselves once they were no
**  longer in use. However, the end result is the same.
*/

IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Files_Temporary]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Files_Temporary];

IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Header_Temporary]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Header_Temporary];
```

On the end disable `xp_cmdshell` and delete Import folder.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would create a small VBA script to convert all TXT files in a folder to XLS files, and then load each into SQL Server tables like you described.

```
select * 
into SQLServerTable FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
    'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\your_path_here\test.xls;HDR=YES', 
    'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

See this for details.

http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=49926

As for the process of converting TXT files to XLS files, try this.

```
Private Declare Function SetCurrentDirectoryA Lib _
        "kernel32" (ByVal lpPathName As String) As Long

Public Function ChDirNet(szPath As String) As Boolean
'based on Rob Bovey's code
    Dim lReturn As Long
    lReturn = SetCurrentDirectoryA(szPath)
    ChDirNet = CBool(lReturn <> 0)
End Function

Sub Get_TXT_Files()
'For Excel 2000 and higher
    Dim Fnum As Long
    Dim mysheet As Worksheet
    Dim basebook As Workbook
    Dim TxtFileNames As Variant
    Dim QTable As QueryTable
    Dim SaveDriveDir As String
    Dim ExistFolder As Boolean

    'Save the current dir
    SaveDriveDir = CurDir

    'You can change the start folder if you want for
    'GetOpenFilename,you can use a network or local folder.
    'For example ChDirNet("C:\Users\Ron\test")
    'It now use Excel's Default File Path

    ExistFolder = ChDirNet("C:\your_path_here\Text\")
    If ExistFolder = False Then
        MsgBox "Error changing folder"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    TxtFileNames = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    (filefilter:="TXT Files (*.txt), *.txt", MultiSelect:=True)

    If IsArray(TxtFileNames) Then

        On Error GoTo CleanUp

        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .EnableEvents = False
        End With

        'Add workbook with one sheet
        Set basebook = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

        'Loop through the array with txt files
        For Fnum = LBound(TxtFileNames) To UBound(TxtFileNames)

            'Add a new worksheet for the name of the txt file
            Set mysheet = Worksheets.Add(After:=basebook. _
                                Sheets(basebook.Sheets.Count))
            On Error Resume Next
            mysheet.Name = Right(TxtFileNames(Fnum), Len(TxtFileNames(Fnum)) - _
                                    InStrRev(TxtFileNames(Fnum), "\", , 1))
            On Error GoTo 0

            With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
                        "TEXT;" & TxtFileNames(Fnum), Destination:=Range("A1"))
                .TextFilePlatform = xlWindows
                .TextFileStartRow = 1

                'This example use xlDelimited
                'See a example for xlFixedWidth below the macro
                .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited

                'Set your Delimiter to true
                .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
                .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
                .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
                .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False

                'Set the format for each column if you want (Default = General)
                'For example Array(1, 9, 1) to skip the second column
                .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 9, 1)

                'xlGeneralFormat  General          1
                'xlTextFormat     Text             2
                'xlMDYFormat      Month-Day-Year   3
                'xlDMYFormat      Day-Month-Year   4
                'xlYMDFormat      Year-Month-Day   5
                'xlMYDFormat      Month-Year-Day   6
                'xlDYMFormat      Day-Year-Month   7
                'xlYDMFormat      Year-Day-Month   8
                'xlSkipColumn     Skip             9

                ' Get the data from the txt file
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            End With
        ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1).Delete
        Next Fnum

        'Delete the first sheet of basebook
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        basebook.Worksheets(1).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        On Error GoTo 0

CleanUp:

        ChDirNet SaveDriveDir

        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

You can setup Windows Scheduler to run the process automatically for you as frequently as desired.