# I am getting file not found on xp_cmdshell dir on local directory

Tags: file, xp-cmdshell

Here is what I am trying to execute:

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'dir "D:\Data\GS Products" /AD /S /B'
```

This works with every other folder on data that I have tried but not with the one I am trying to use. I am logged in with the admin god privs, I have done the `sp_configure` to enable cmdshell and I have used this with other folders that have spaces in the name. Is it permissions? And if so, how can I check that?  When I look at the properties of the folder it says the admin account has FULL permissions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, didnt get much help this time, but maybe I did it wrong..anyway, I had to add the SQL Service account pemissions to the folder I was doing the command on.  Even though I was logged in with the top admin login, it did not work until I added the permissions to the folder/subfolders.

Comment: I know this is down the road a ways from the original question, but this did it for me. I have been tearing me hair out over the issue. I had permissions for everything I could think of - user accounts, domain group, SQL Server proxy acount - nothing worked. The xp_cmdshell procedure kept throwing the error "Cannot find drive D", until out of desperation, after finding this thread, I added Everyone. Suddenly it works!!

Can you explain to me, in very small words, why does that work, when (seemingly) all the appropriate explicit permissions did not?

Comment: To be more specific, what is enabled by allowing 'Everyone', that does not get enabled by specifying the particular users and services that I want to allow? Your answer of enabling access for 'Everyone' is what made my setup work, but I don't understand why. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Right click folder you are importing from and click **Properties**, go to **Security** tab click **Edit**.

Add `"Everyone"`.

`Apply` and `OK`.

See image for all details:

[image]

Your:

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'dir "D:\Data\ImportFolder" /AD /S /B'
```

will work now.

*Note:*
*`xp_cmdshell` needs only read permissions so you don't have to put full. I needed full because script I have need to write log file on the end in same folder.*